# SEO: How to handle common content to multiple countries (subfolder strucuture) that has "local links" depending on the country

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url, geotargeting, geotagging

## Goal: SEO-friendly muti-country mono-language web with common contents across countries that need local links

I have to build a SEO-optimized website with:

- MULTI-country (multiple Spanish-speaking countries)
- MONO-language (all them in Spanish)

## Country structure

When there's country-dependant content, the country URL structure will be subfolder. For example Spain will be `/es/`, Colombia `/co/`, Mexico `/mx/` and so on.

## Page categories

There are 2 big categories of pages:

- Local content for some cities. For example shops in Barcelona (Spain), Barranquilla (Colombia) or Tijuana (Mexico).
- Global content (articles in Spanish that are **common** to all countries).

## URL structure for LOCAL pages

There are cities whose name is "repeated" in multiple countries but they refer to different city:

- Guadalajara is both a city in Spain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guadalajara,_Spain and in Mexico https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guadalajara_metropolitan_area

Therefore I'll use this scheme: `/country/city/city-level-content-for-example-shops`

- `www.example.com/es/guadalajara/local-content-here-for-spain-guadalajara`
- `www.example.com/mx/guadalajara/local-content-here-for-mexico-guadalajara`

Up to here no problem

## The problem: The global content

But I have GLOBAL content that will meet these criteria:

- It's **common** to all countries (it's not tuned to every country, it's global).
- The content will have, below the "main global text", a set of links to the local content related to that global content. For example if I talk about a book, links to local libraries.

I have 2 possible strategies:

### No geo separation for the global content

- `www.example.com/global-content-here-with-local-links-conditional-server-side-with-ip-location`

With this approach, I'll have to display the local links doing server-logic, doing some sort of IP geo-location and guess if the person is in Mexico or Spain or Colombia and place one link or another.

**PROBLEM:** This would potentially confuse crawler bots getting only a portion of the links and not understanding the structure.

### Do content-duplication for the global content just to change the links

- `www.example.com/es/barcelona/global-content-here-with-local-links-to-spain-barcelona`
- `www.example.com/es/guadalajara/global-content-here-with-local-links-to-spain-guadalajara`
- `www.example.com/mx/tijuana/global-content-here-with-local-links-to-mexico-tijuana`
- `www.example.com/mx/guadalajara/global-content-here-with-local-links-to-mexico-guadalajara`

Here the structure will be perfect for the crawlers.

**PROBLEM:** The main content will be N*M-duplicated if there are N countries and M cities in each country, and it's commonly known that duplicating content penalizes a lot.

## Possible solutions?

I think it's not about using `hreflang` as it's not about the LANGUAGE but the COUNTRY and/or COUNTRY+CITY. All the content is in Spanish.

## Question

What's the SEO-friendly correct way of handling this situation?

Comment: Google does not penalize a page or the website for duplicative content. Googlebot basically ignores the subsequent or non-canonical versions that it comes across (or at least it does most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

You can use city-specific URLs if you are targeting multi-county and multi-city markets. It's a clearly to tell google your geo targeting site structures. Though I would suggest you not to use duplicate content for various cities, but to edit the content to be location specific.

For your global content, you can simply set up a default page and use hreflang tag as `hreflang="x-default"`. If your visitor is not from your targeted cities, it will auto show the default global content in the search engine results.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is whether Googlebot will come to learn the "global" and "local" structures of the site, then itemize each version in your XML site map, add/inject the appropriate hreflang tags to the head section of each page, and use breadcrumbs (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) to further indicate how the pages relate to one another structurally.

A local page's breadcrumbs structured data could be like:

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Homepage",
    "item": "[url]"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "name": "Mexico",
    "item": "[url]"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "name": "guadalajara",
    "item": "[url]"
  }]
}
```

Also, you should also add links that reflect the typical navigation to page in its local structure somewhere on the page as well (https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G65.html):

```
**Homepage** > **Mexico** > Guadalajara 
                               ^ leave the self-referencing one as text though
```

For Global pages, it sounds like they follow the "Global > [page]" schematization so have their breadcrumbs reflect that fact.

Answer (score 0):

> The content will have, below the "main global text", a set of links to
> the local content related to that global content. For example if I
> talk about a book, links to local libraries.

With local content, do the opposite: for example, when talking about a book in the library, link about that book in the global content. This will create linked data between the book and the libraries where the book is available.